# Create an array to produce a hierarchical tree structure in laravel using eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent, tree, laravel-blade

I have a project with table structure:

There are professors on top
**tb_professor**

id  name

1   david

2   mathew

3   tom

The second table is of guest lecturers. Here its bit complicated. If the guest lecturer is experienced, they can teach other guest lecture who doesnt have experience.The experienced guest lectures will be selected at first. Then freshers.

**tb_guest_lec**

id name  fk_professor_id is_experienced trainee_id

1  sara      1              1             null

2  jasha     1              1             null

3  sam       1              0             null

4  william   1              0              1

5  luk       3              0              1

The last table is students table. Each guest lecures are assigned with students
**tb_students**

id  name   fk_gust_lec_id

1   liza      1

2   james     1

3   mason     2

Finally need a hierarchial tree structure. professors on top, underneith guest lectures, and at lowest level students(also a group of guest lecturers under experienced lectureers )

```
$res=array();
$gl=$res['guest_lec']= DB::table('tb_guest_lec')->where('fk_professor_id','1')->select(count('id'), *)->get()->toArray();

forech($gl as $g){
    if($g['is_experienced']==1){
      $res['freshers']= DB::table('tb_guest_lec')->select(count('id'), *)->where('trainee_id',$g['id'])->get();
    }
    $res['students']= DB::table('tb_students')->select(count('id'), *)->where('fk_gust_lec_id',$g['id'])->get();
}

var_dump($res);
```

In blade, by looping through the array can create a tree structure.

But can i do this in a simple way using **eloquent**?

Comment: Your question might be a little broad for Stackoverflow, but one piece of advice is to use models and relationships. A recursive relationship is definitely possible, but you're hindering yourself by using `DB::table()` vs `Model::with()`

Comment: I'm able to join two tables. But how can I three?